# Como retornar os dados cadastrado no banco usando Sqlite3

Tags: javascript, sqlite3, knex.js

Estou usando o knexJS com SQlite3, consegui fazer o insert e está cadastrando os dados normalmente no banco, porém quando eu envio os dados pelo nodemon, ele me retorna só o id, e não os dados cadastrados.

Pesquisei e notei que o Sqlite3 retorna o id como padrão, e não sei como resolver isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tem que passar o parametro returning com as tabelas que deseja ou * para todas ex: ["user", "id"]

Comment: (um ano de atraso)Primeira orientação que deveria ser passada é a não publicação de código, logs ou mensagens de erro como imagem. Essas informações devem ser publicadas como texto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/137387 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635

Answer (score -1):

Quando estamos falando do Knex.js, ele espera que você passe um `returning` como segundo parâmetro no método `insert`.

Nesse caso você tem duas opções:

```
knex.insert({title: 'Great Gatsby'}, ['*']).into('books')
```

Ou

```
knex('books')
   .returning('*')
   .insert({title: 'Slaughterhouse Five'})
```

O comportamento padrão do Knex não é trazer estes dados no insert, então você tem que ou usar o `returning` explicitamente ou o segundo parâmetro do `insert` que é um atalho.

Mais informações podem ser vistas na [documentação](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert).

Comment: Então Marcos eu agradeço a sua atenção porém o problema é que o Sqlite3 não suporta o returning(); entende?

Comment: Ah, entendi. No SQL quase não mexi :/

Answer (score -2):

```
const connection = require("../database/connection");
```

> Arquivo do connection

```
const knex = require("knex");
const config = require("../../knexfile");

const connection = knex(config.development);

module.exports = connection;
```

pode passar os nomes das variáveis separado por virgula, conforme o modelo abaixo do id.

```
const [id] = await connection("users").insert(dados);
```

ou fazer uma query explicita:

```
await connection.raw('sua query aqui')
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).